# Using count(*) with rownum

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count the number of time a customer request and order and only display the first 10 output. I use count and rownum function as shown below but the count of order is not implemented in the code. Please see my code below and I will appreciate any advice to fix the issue. Thank You.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON
create or replace procedure total is
begin
for a in (select customer_no, count(*) as total from orders where rownum <= 
10 group by customer_no)
loop
dbms_output.put_line('customer number '||a.customer_no|| ' total orders 
'||a.total);

end loop;
end;
/
execute total;
drop procedure total;
```

**Output sample with rownum**

```
Procedure TOTAL compiled

customer number 1062 total orders 1
customer number 1054 total orders 1
customer number 1051 total orders 1
customer number 1060 total orders 1
customer number 1052 total orders 1
customer number 1059 total orders 1
customer number 1061 total orders 1
customer number 1055 total orders 1
customer number 1053 total orders 1
customer number 1058 total orders 1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Procedure TOTAL dropped.
```

**Output sample without rownum:**

```
Procedure TOTAL compiled

customer number 1098 total orders 25
customer number 1041 total orders 11
customer number 1000 total orders 18
customer number 1003 total orders 16



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Procedure TOTAL dropped.
```

Comment: Can you give sample input and expected output ?

Comment: have you tried using LIMIT 10 instead? I don't think rownum will play well with GROUP BY

Comment: @shrek I add the output sample. Thanks for your help

Comment: @arth am using sql developer which is not recognizing LIMIT as inbuilt function. Can you please provide an example with LIMIT if you think I can use that. Thank You.

Comment: I don't understand. First, what is the requirement? Compute the count for each customer, and then list just the ten customers with the highest counts? If this is it, your attempt does nothing of the sort. Then, why are you using a procedure? This is a simple SQL statement.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot Oracle SQL doesn't support LIMIT

Comment: @mathguy please ignore the procedure. You nailed the question, but I only want to output the first ten output without ranking them. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want 10 rows, without caring about which 10 or what order they're in?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT customer_no, count(*) AS total
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY customer_no)
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59091/1)

(Oracle 12 reportedly supports a FETCH FIRST syntax for returning a given number of rows, but I don't have any way of testing that)

Comment: Works fine for me. I don't also have oracle 12. Thank You.